# Restrict the number of http and https connections from a specified IP address to ten connections per minute

Tags: iptables

How I can restrict the number of http and https connections from a specified IP address to ten per minute using`iptables` commands?

I’ve tried this but it is not working:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.100 -p tcp -m multiport --destination-port 80,443 -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 10/min -j ACCEPT
```

and somebody tells me that you must use recent  module!

What about this way?

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --match multiports --dport http,https -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name HTTP

iptables -A INPUT -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 11 --name HTTP -j ACCEPT
```

still not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the following iptables command:

```
iptables –A INPUT –s $IP_Address –p tcp –m multiport –-destination-port 80,443 –m state --state NEW –m limit -–limit 10/min –j ACCEPT
```

Network Security Course?...

Comment: What am I missing?  As far as I can tell, aside from the cosmetic substitution of `$IP_Address` for the actual IP address, your answer is the same as the first command given in the question –– where the OP states that it doesn’t work.

Comment: I've finally find where is the problem!!i forget to append DROP  in the end of the list :)

Comment: @arashams: If you have found an answer, then post it _as an answer_ and accept it.

Comment: append DROP in the end of the list